# What is the limit of POST Method? and how to post large number of inputs in php?

Tags: php

I have about 1300 check boxes in a form and want to post them using form but on server i can only get about 1000 of them, What is the best way to post them?

I was searching but could not find solution of my problem except increasing server size. Problem is i have no access to server configuration, Is there an y other possible way?

Comment: `1300 check boxes in a form` So somehow you should rethink your design

Comment: The `max_input_vars` setting defaults to 1000, but can be changed in your php.ini..... but that's an insane number of checkboxes, and is never going to be a good user experience.... expect lots of your users to give up filling in that form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure `php.ini` file.

```
ini_set('max_input_vars', 3000);
```

You can set the count to your required count in place of 3000.

OR,

If you do not have access to `php.ini`, you can set it in `.htaccess` file for folders (specifically root folder):

Adding the directive into `php.ini` or placing following lines into .htaccess will work:

```
php_value max_input_vars 3000
```

[Referene](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars)

Comment: i have no access to that, is there any other option?

Comment: can u tell me full htaccess code for that? i am working in codeigniter, should i put htaccess file on root or in view for this fprm?

Comment: You need to put .htaccess in root folder. You can get easily .htaccess file if you search for it.

Comment: Added codde in .htaccess file and put that in root folder still not  working

Answer (score 2):

`php.ini` you check or change your post limit

```
post_max_size=20M
upload_max_filesize=20M
```

Comment: can u let me know where to put custom php.ini file in Codeigniter structure? and complete code of php.ini?

Comment: if you use lampp path is:- **/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini** @ImranQamer

Comment: i want to ask that in root folder i have application, system, assets etc folder with index file, should i put .ini file there